Bootstrap Fails on Cassandra node - Unable to join the cluster
The bootstrap fails with following Stream Error.
Existing Cluster
6 Node - CentOS 7 - Cassandra version 4.0.11
The new node being added to the existing cluster - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Cassandra version 4.0.14
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/x.x.x.x:7000-7879f952] 2024-11-22 05:20:52,935 StreamSession.java:731 - [Stream #7d3711a0-a891-11ef-903f-c9da906269c9] Streaming error occurred on session with peer x.x.x.:7000
org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveException: java.lang.AssertionError: Invalid arguments: cell:43764 point:-2144718900 delta:1
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingStreamMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingStreamMessage.java:60)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingStreamMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingStreamMessage.java:38)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:53)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingInboundHandler$StreamDeserializingTask.run(StreamingInboundHandler.java:172)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Invalid arguments: cell:43764 point:-2144718900 delta:1
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.streamhist.StreamingTombstoneHistogramBuilder$Spool.tryCell(StreamingTombstoneHistogramBuilder.java:496)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.streamhist.StreamingTombstoneHistogramBuilder$Spool.tryAddOrAccumulate(StreamingTombstoneHistogramBuilder.java:471)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.streamhist.StreamingTombstoneHistogramBuilder.update(StreamingTombstoneHistogramBuilder.java:106)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.streamhist.StreamingTombstoneHistogramBuilder.update(StreamingTombstoneHistogramBuilder.java:93)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataCollector.updateLocalDeletionTime(MetadataCollector.java:218)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataCollector.update(MetadataCollector.java:184)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.Rows.collectStats(Rows.java:106)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter$StatsCollector.applyToRow(BigTableWriter.java:284)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseRows.hasNext(BaseRows.java:141)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnIndex.buildRowIndex(ColumnIndex.java:117)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.append(BigTableWriter.java:216)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.append(SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.java:48)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.RangeAwareSSTableWriter.append(RangeAwareSSTableWriter.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraStreamReader.writePartition(CassandraStreamReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraCompressedStreamReader.read(CassandraCompressedStreamReader.java:98)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.streaming.CassandraIncomingFile.read(CassandraIncomingFile.java:84)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingStreamMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingStreamMessage.java:53)
    ... 5 common frames omitted


Tried to bootstrap multiple times, it fails with the same error

Can you try adding a new node running Cassandra 4.0.11? Like Mario stated below, I wonder if this is an issue in version mismatch.

@Aaron: I tried that, the same error is thrown. Unable to join the cluster. The bootstrap fails

Your existing cluster is running Cassandra 4.0.11, while the new node is on Cassandra 4.0.14.
While minor version differences are usually supported within the same major version (4.x), it's possible that a bug fix or behavioral change introduced between these versions is causing this.
In particular, the stack trace references:
StreamingTombstoneHistogramBuilder This suggests an issue with tombstone metadata handling during SSTable streaming.
This kind of error is uncommon for a minor version mismatch, but Cassandra has had bugs in earlier 4.x versions related to streaming and tombstone histograms, which were resolved in later updates.
What I would suggest is to upgrade the existing cluster to 4.0.14, repair the data, and try again.
An alternative is to downgrade the new version if upgrading the existing cluster is not an option.

I tried the second approach of downgrading the new nodes to 4.0.11 and trying to add it to the cluster, getting the same errors.

Two things pop into my mind that can create that issue:
1)corrupted SSTable. To solve this run a nodetool scrub on the cluster https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/tools/nodetool/scrub.html (the command can take a lot of time, also days).
2) Tombstones. Check if you have tons of tombstones in your tables, you can use tools like nodetool tablestats https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/tools/nodetool/tablestats.html
2

One thing your could try would be to set auto_bootstrap: false, and then join the node to the cluster. It will join empty, so you should immediately run a nodetool repair or rebuild on it. Perhaps running the joining and streaming processes separately will yield some results.

Let me give it a try, and will post the results here
